# Show a column value but submit another value in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-office

I am trying to make a simple form that 'registers' users into a meeting. I'm trying to get the form to submit the meeting 'id' into the database but I wish to display a different value for the user (so that they do not stumble through meeting id's). I've added two columns to the query (meeting id and meeting information) but I am unsure how I would get the form to submit the meeting ID but display the meeting information for the current user.

**EDIT: I've tried your method Chris but it doesn't seem to work.**

Edits made:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IUuD.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PTTZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a rowsource query with TWO values because you have two columns. For example:

```
SELECT meeting_id, meeting_name
FROM meetings
```

In this case the 'bound column' property would be '1' because in the example you first select the meeting_id.

In the 'column width' property you then type "0cm;4cm". 0cm means that the first column (the IDs) will not be shown.

Comment: Thank you, this method worked. It took me a while to understand it but I got there in the end.

Answer (score 0):

go to design view of the form and change the bound column to the number that represents the column you desire to have displayed. eg.

[image]

You can add the query at the Row Source as in the image a query builder will appear and you just create the query and save it.

Comment: Hi, I've done what you've suggested but it doesn't work. If it helps I've included the structures: 
Query: [link]http://i.stack.imgur.com/PJnZ0.png
Query Structure: [link]http://i.stack.imgur.com/BS4wz.png

Comment: Unless you want the user to see the meeting ID you don't need to return meeting ID just `SELECT MeetingType From MeetingInfo` I've added where you could do this to the answer